# Laravel Assessor With Collection Failing request

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use a laravel mutator doing a small logic inside and it fail my request. I don't know why. Have a look my set

My Assesor in model:

```
public function getTimeToServeAttribute()
{
    $turns = $this->siblingsInQueue;
    $currentTurn = $this->id;
    $position = $turns->search(function ($turn) use ($currentTurn) {
        return $currentTurn == $turn->id;
    }) + 1;
    return $position * $this->queue->average_time; // minutes
}
```

Relation in same model:

```
public function siblingsInQueue()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Turn::class, 'queue_id', 'queue_id')
        ->where('turn_status_id', TurnStatus::IN_QUEUE)
        ->orderBy('order');
}
```

Append it:

```
protected $appends = [
    'time_to_serve'
];
```

If I print the result in my model, there is no error, and looks right, but when I do my request, error:

[image: If I print the result in my model, there is no error, and looks right, but when I do my request, error]

Comment: are you returning anything from the controller?

Comment: Yes, my data collected.. if I remove the append, then it works

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the siblingsInQueue, I think it is interpreted as siblings_in_queue in Laravel if you try to get it directly.

Try using `$this->siblingsInQueue()->get();` instead.

```
public function getTimeToServeAttribute()
{
    $turns = $this->siblingsInQueue()->get();
    $currentTurn = $this->turn;
    $position = $turns->search(function ($turn) use ($currentTurn) {
        return $currentTurn == $turn->id;
    }) + 1;
    return $position * $this->queue->average_time; // minutes
}
```

Comment: Nope, same error.. Its pending for a little while and then fails

Comment: @EzequielFernandez if that's the case then, I think your script is getting a timeout.

Comment: yeah.. might be because its a too large response?